# How to return records of associated models using Typeahead?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using the [twitter-typeahead-rails](https://github.com/yourabi/twitter-typeahead-rails) gem, which is built on [typeahead](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) and [bloodhound](https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md). I'm using it to return results with AJAX while a user is typing into a search bar. Right now, it searches for instances of my model `Product` where `product.name` matches the search key. This part works great.

What I'm trying to do is return an associated record, along with the original result. My `Product` has a `belongs_to` relationship with `Merchant`. So for example, when I type in a search key, I want the results to also list the Merchant associated with each Product, like this:

```
return "<div>" + product.name + product.merchant.name +</div>";
```

but right now, adding `product.merchant.name` breaks the function, so I think the merchant isn't being included in the JSON. How do I include it?

**Controller**

```
def typeahead
  q = params[:query]
  render json: Product.where('name like ?', "%#{q}%")
end
```

**HTML/JS**

```
<%= form_tag products_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id:"typeahead" %>
    <%= image_tag("Go.png", type:"submit") %>
<% end %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
      },
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY'
    });
    bloodhound.initialize();

    $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
      displayKey: function(product) {
        return "" + product.name + "";
      },
      source: bloodhound.ttAdapter(),
      templates: {
        suggestion: function (product) {
          var thing_url = "<%=root_url%>pages/"
          return "<div>" + product.name + </div>";
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails', '0.10.5'
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried including `Merchant` in the query:

```
Product.includes(:merchants).where('name like ?', "%#{q}%")
```

and then tried returning the `merchant.name` in the results:

```
return "<div>" + product.name + product.merchant.name </div>";
```

but adding `product.merchant.name` breaks the function entirely, so now I'm getting no results at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render to JSON you have to explicitly tell ActiveModel Serializer to include the associated objects.

render :json => @products, :include => {:merchant=> {:only => :name}}

Answer (score 1):

try including merchants in query like this

```
Product.includes(:merchants).where('name like ?', "%#{q}%")
```

Comment: I updated my question. I'm trying to print the merchant.name in my results, but `product.merchant.name` breaks my function entirely. How can I access `merchant` in my results?

Comment: try to get first merchant name. I assume there is many-to-many  relationship b/w product and merchants.
Use "product.merchants.first.name" instead of "product.merchant.name"

Comment: No, Merchant has_many of Product, and Product belongs_to Merchant. Unfortunately I can't view the error because it's all done over ajax, but with  hraynaud's code, `product.merchant.name` finally works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user id to product as something like owner_id, then you can query also with

```
@owner = User.find_by(id: @product.owner_id)
```

Comment: But `product` is returned as a javascript variable. How would I pass that into a rails query?